# getting error like unprocessable entity in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, react-hooks

when am trying to fetch request from backend then getting an error like unprocessable entity and i entered correct 10 digit in mobile no still getting error
don't know where am wrong plz help

please checkout

https://ibb.co/NtqkfLt

> ********* FRONTEND ************
> Todo.js

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Todo = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [pass, setPass] = useState("");

    const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/addcontact`,{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                name,
                pass,
            })
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="text-center">Registration Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={register}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputEmail1"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputPassword1"
                        value={pass}
                        onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Todo;
```

> ************Backend**************
> app.js

This is the main file of our backend project where i connect my mongodb

```
require('dotenv').config()

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex:true
    }).then(() =>{
        console.log('DB CONNECTED');
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(cors());

    app.use('/api', authRoute);

     const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

     app.listen(port,() =>{
         console.log(`app is running at ${port}`);
     });
```

> auth.js

This is the Auth Route where i wrote my whole route and all logic part in cotroller section

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {check} = require('express-validator');
const {addContact,getAllContacts,deleteContact, updateContact} = require('../controller/auth');

//ROUTERS

router.post('/addcontact',[
    check('name',"name should be 3 chaacter").isLength({min : 3}),
    check('mob_no',"mobile no should be 10 digit").isLength({min : 10}),
],addContact);

router.get('/getallcontact',getAllContacts);

router.delete('/deletecontact/:contactid',deleteContact)

router.put('/updatecontact/:contactid',updateContact);
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the post route you check the `mob_no` like this:

```
check('mob_no',"mobile no should be 10 digit").isLength({min : 10})
```

but in the request you don't put the `mob_no` field in the `body` so delete `check('mob_no)' in router or put the value in the body of request

Comment: when i delete mob_no from router then getting new error like "Not able to store data in DB"

Comment: if you want to store mobile number, should be a value for mob_no in the request, because in the request there are just two fileds (name and pass), maybe in the schema you set mob_no : required